# Trying to parse string values into an array after a pattern match

Tags: regex, parsing, match

I have the following lines in a text file:

```
<Entry>
    <Key argument="ComputerNames"/>
    <Value type="string" argument="localhost,localhost,engine1,engine2"/></Entry>
<Entry>
    <Key argument="BranchIDMultiple"/>
    <Value type="int" argument="1"/></Entry>
```

I know how to find the line that has ComputerNames.  I know how to read the next line as well.

I need to parse the line as follows where the number of arguments can be dynamic.   Parse output should be:

```
@result = $result[0]=localhost, $result[1]=localhost, $result[2]=engine1, $result[3]=engine2.
```

There must be at least one argument, but there can be more as well..

I'm not able to construct the right regex to accomplish the split.   Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Let's say input contains your following xml line.

Since you've mentioned that you know how to extract this line. I've left that portion to you.

After you got this line use the following regex

```
String regex ="argument=\"[a-zA-Z0-9,]*\"" ;

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);

Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
String[] op;
if(matcher.find())
 {
   op = input.subString(matcher.start(),matcher.end()).split(",");
 }
```

Comment: Hello! Thank you for your code sample. I am not 100% on the following:

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);

Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);

I see that my incoming line of text will be the input correct? Also, the regex is compiled into pattern.matcher so that String{} will contain as many values as found by the split. Please let me know if I am on track. Thank You!

Comment: I assume input will contain only "<Value type="string" argument="localhost,localhost,engine1,engine2"/></Entry>" this value

Answer (score 0):

Ok, Here is what I have:

--- After many different trials, I was finally able to get something that works.  See below:

```
BEGIN { require 5.8.0; }

use strict; 
use warnings;

# string to test regular expressions
my $test_string = '<Value type="string" argument="400teets,localhost,localhost,engine1,engine2,engine50,engine100,100afdasfdas"/></Entry>';

# print out the initial string
print "The initial string is: $test_string\n\n";

# first set of arguments - all words that have a comma after them
my @first_words = ($test_string =~ /(\w+),/g);

# print first set of arguments
print "\nFirst set of arguments found\n";
foreach my $word (@first_words) {
    print "$word\n";
}

# second set of arguments - all words that have a comma before them
my @last_words = ($test_string =~ /,(\w+)/g);

#print second set of arguments
print "\nSecond set of arguments found\n";
foreach my $word (@last_words) {
    print "$word\n";
}

#merge the sets by popping the last element off of last_words array and pushing it into the first_words array
push(@first_words,pop(@last_words));

#print the results
print "\nMerged Sets\n";
foreach my $word (@first_words) {
    print "$word\n";
}

# END OF PROGRAM
```

--- Really, if you exclude all of the print statements and comments, all you really need is these three lines:

```
my @first_words = ($test_string =~ /(\w+),/g);
my @last_words = ($test_string =~ /,(\w+)/g);
push(@first_words,pop(@last_words));
```

--- Here is the output:

The initial string is:

First set of arguments found
400teets
localhost
localhost
engine1
engine2
engine50
engine100

Second set of arguments found
localhost
localhost
engine1
engine2
engine50
engine100
100afdasfdas

Merged Sets
400teets
localhost
localhost
engine1
engine2
engine50
engine100
100afdasfdas